# Fetching CBitmap out of CImageList

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I inserted bitmaps in CImageList in one Function and needed to change some of the images later in another function.  But I am unable to extract the CBitmap. The code goes something like this:

```
CBitmap GetIndividualBitmap(CImageList oImgList, int nBmpNo)
{   
    IMAGEINFO imgInfo;
    imagelist.GetImageInfo(index,imgInfo);
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.FromHandle(imgInfo.hbmImage);
    return bmp;
}
```

However all I get is a black screen.  Could anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Ok there are a number of errors in your code

1)You are passing the Image list by object which means it will copy it across.  Passing it by reference is a far better plan.
2) You are not passing a pointer to the IMAGEINFO struct into the GetImageInfo.
3) You misunderstand how "FromHandle" works.  FromHandle is a static function that returns a pointer to a Bitmap.  In your code you are calling the function and then ignoring the CBitmap* returned and returning a copy of your newly constructed object (ie it contains nothing) which results in your black screen.

Taking all those into account you should have code that looks like this:

```
CBitmap* GetIndividualBitmap(CImageList& oImgList, int nBmpNo) 
{
    IMAGEINFO imgInfo;
    oImgList.GetImageInfo( nBmpNo, &imgInfo );
    return CBitmap::FromHandle( imgInfo.hbmImage );
}
```

Comment: All very true. However, i believe you will still have to fetch the proper portion of the bitmap as indicated in my comments above.